# How to choose if theorem numerote

Tags: theorems

I'm currently working on a layout that is divided in article and alinea. Basically I've two functions. In each functions there is an environment dedicated to show the texts in a certain layout.
Sometimes there are many alineas in an article. But sometimes, there's only one. In that case, I would like to Not show the number of the alinea. But, I don't know how to achieve that.
I was thinking to use some conditions... but I don't know how to retrieve the number of alineas in the environment of the articles as there are resets to 0 as a last instruction in that environment.
As anyone an idea? thanks for your reading and maybe your help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newtheorem{article}{Art.}

\newtheorem{alinea}{}%nom du théorème ; ce qui apparaît ; devant quoi la numérotation reprend de à 1
\newcommand{\resettheoremcounters}{%va remettre à zéro le compteur
  \setcounter{alinea}{0}%
} 
\newcommand{\art}[1]{\begin{article}#1\end{article}%
                                    \resettheoremcounters}
\newcommand{\ali}[1]{\begin{alinea}#1\end{alinea}}  

\begin{document}
    \art{
        \ali{ali 1}
        }
    \art{
        \ali{ali 1}
        \ali{ali 2}
        }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of `\ali` command inside the argument to `\art`; do it inside a box that's then discarded.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newtheorem{article}{Art.}

\newtheorem{alinea}{}[article]
\renewcommand{\thealinea}{\arabic{alinea}}

\newcommand{\art}[1]{%
  \setcounter{countali}{0}%
  \setbox0=\vbox{\let\ali\countali#1}%
  \begin{article}
  \ifnum\value{countali}<2
    \let\ali\ignoreali
  \fi
  #1%
  \end{article}
}
\newcommand{\ali}[1]{\begin{alinea}#1\end{alinea}}
\newcounter{countali}
\newcommand{\countali}[1]{\stepcounter{countali}}
\newcommand{\ignoreali}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\art{
  \ali{ali 1}
}

\art{
  \ali{ali 1}
  \ali{ali 2}
}

\art{
  \ali{ali 1}
  \ali{ali 2}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\newtheorem{ali}{}[article]` you get automatic resetting without the need of issuing an explicit command.